# Preventing repetition in nested if

Tags: python, if-statement, nested, repeat

I’ve got a large Jason file which I would like to interate trough and count some occurrences.  The json file contains 12 different types of ‘foo’ and every ‘foo’ can have one of 12 predefined statuses like ‘opened’, ‘closed’, ‘parked’, ‘under investigation’ e.g.

If I approach it as shown below, I get a lot of repetitive code, but I have no clue on how to get a more lean code.

```
if foo == 'Foo1':
  Foo1.opened += 1 
  Foo1.closed += 1 
  Foo1.parked += 1 

elif foo == 'Foo2': 
  Foo2.opened += 1 
  Foo2.closed += 1 
  Foo2.parked += 1 

elif foo == 'Foo3':
  ...
```

Comment: Without knowing more details I would say use a dictionary.

Comment: 1. Store Foos in a list. So instead of Foo1 you have Foos[0]. Then index is `int(foo[3:])-1` 2. Make a function getting a Foo. `def f(Foo): Foo.opened+=1; Foo.closed+=1; Foo.parked+=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This avoids repetition without introducing any drastic changes:

```
if foo == 'Foo1':
  foo_bar = Foo1
elif foo == 'Foo2': 
  foo_bar = Foo2
elif foo == 'Foo3':
  foo_bar = Foo3
  
foo_bar.opened += 1
foo_bar.closed += 1
foo_bar.parked += 1
```

Or you could define a dictionary with your items:

```
dict_foo = {'Foo1': Foo1, 'Foo2': Foo2, 'Foo3': Foo3}
foo_bar = dict_foo[foo]
foo_bar.opened += 1
foo_bar.closed += 1
foo_bar.parked += 1
```

There are plenty of other options, these are just a couple of simple ones.